# How to call directive on submit button

Tags: html, angularjs

I need to call directive on submit button so that after click on button they redirect me on register.html page. What can I do?

My JavaScript file is:

```
var abc=angular.module("myAppE", []);
abc.directive('xyz', function () {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    templateUrl:"register.html"
  }
});
```

Comment: I think you need to specify "what i want?"

Comment: why you want to do redirect with directive? Any specific need?

Comment: call a directive means i want to display register.html page click on submit button @tanmay

Comment: Because i need to change only page content,  not a page url.. means that suppose i have home page and after click on button it display register.html, when doing this task that url will remain same and i want to dispaly register.html page content

Comment: that submit button call a directive that containe "templatUrl:register.html" @tanmay

Comment: that's weird.. maybe a modal suits here.. otherwise, you can have a boolean variable to hide everything else and show the directive on submit..

Comment: how to show directive on submit?? @tanmay

Comment: As I said, have a boolean variable in scope/controller to do that